# how can I change the bot response format from adaptive cards to text format while reading from JSON file, so that bot works fine with skype channel

Tags: c#

I have a bot code where the bot responses are in adaptive card format which is not supported in skype, now I want to make changes the code such that the bot responses are sent in text format so that bot works fine with skype channel. In this application I'm reading from JSON template to generate the response

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: In order to make my bot work for skype channel, what changes I should make in my code as skype doesn't support adaptive card reponse?

Comment: in order to advise you what changes you need to do to your code, we'll need to see some of your code first, don't we?

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the channel ID from the context by using:
`var channel = context.Activity.ChannelId`
or from the IMessageActivity as shown below, and based on the channel construct the reply message in a different way. C# Example:

```
public static async Task ConstructMessage(IDialogContext context, IMessageActivity msg)
{
      switch (msg.ChannelId)
      {
            case "skypeforbusiness":
                // Do Something Specific
                break;
            case "emulator":
            case "skype":
                break;
            case "msteams":
                break;
            default:
                break;
      }
}
```